# lightning:recordEditForm. Override submit retrieve undefined on event.getParam('fields')

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

I had a working code on Winter 18 which override the standard submit event on recordEditForm component but it is not working on Spring 19. When I try to retrieve fields using *event.getParam('fields');* it returns *undefined*.

This is my code:

.cmp

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm
                                          aura:id="editForm"
                                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                          objectApiName="E2PC_Wallet_Share__c"
                                          onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                          onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"  >

                    <lightning:messages />

...
Some input fields
...

               <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button label="{!$Label.c.E2PC_Cerrar}" onclick="{!c.cancel}" variant ="neutral"/>
                <lightning:button label="{!$Label.c.E2PC_Guardar}" type="submit" variant ="brand"/>
            </footer>
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

.js

```
handleSubmit: function(component,event,helper){
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var fields = event.getParam('fields');
            console.log(fields.E2PC_Objetivo_Accionable__c);
            var gastoTotal = component.get("v.gastoTotal");
            if (gastoTotal < fields.E2PC_Objetivo_Accionable__c){
                component.find('notifLib').showNotice({
                    "header": "¡Error!",
                    "message": "El objetivo accionable no puede ser mayor que el gasto total"
                }); 
            }else{
                component.find('editForm').submit(fields);
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I replicated the same code and was able to get value of the field. Can you check if the API name is proper or not and `lightning:inputField` is referencing that field?

Comment: please share the `Some input fields` of your markup

Comment: This might be related to a Spring '19 bug that I have a ticket in for now.  I'll post an update here as soon as I have one.

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld did you ever get a response from SF Support? I am also having same issue it worked for me yesterday and then suddenly stopped.

Comment: @apple123 -- I did, but it winds up it wasn't related.  I know we fixed this, but I don't remember what the issue was.  :(  Sorry about that!

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld no problem I was able to figure it out and submit it with ‘component.find(‘theform’).submit()’. I am doing other validation for all fields before I submit and I keep a boolean flag to see if there’s an error. If no error then submit the form. Thanks for the response.